# Adding Links to Reduce Diameter

Tags: graphs, path

Given an unweighted graph $G$, the problem is to add links to the graph with total minimum cost such that the diameter of the graph becomes at most a constant $k$? The cost of adding a link $(u,v)$ is the shortest path length between $u$ and $v$ in $G$.

Has the above problem been looked at? Is it NP-complete?

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397511003963?via%3Dihub) seems closely related. The authors study the same problem you define with the exception that edge costs are uniform and do not depend on the distance of the endpoints.  This version of the problem is NP-hard.

The paper provides references to variants of the problem, some involving costs and lengths. Perhaps you can see if one of the NP-hardness proofs can be easily adapted to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The earlier [paper](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Edodis/ps/diameter.pdf) addresses pretty much the asked problem.